# How to get create and edit option in dropdown in openerp

Tags: openerp-7

i have separate drop down field and at present i have given static values. i need to get dynamic values like a user should able to add the values and should show in the drop down.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can define many2one field for this purpose.

```
_columns = {
             'your_field_name' : fields.many2one('object', string='My field')
           }
```

Example

```
_columns = {
              user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string=u"User")
           }
```

So you will got list of users. Whatever object list you can define many2one field.